# Is there a way to disable Candlestick aggregation in lightningchart js

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am trying to make an application for stocks with lightningchart js. I tried to put 30 days of 1-minute data into the chart but it is aggregating candles.

This is my code

```
const { lightningChart, emptyFill, OHLCFigures } = lcjs;

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ container: document.getElementById('chart-root') })
const ohlcDataArr = []; // contains 30 days 1-min data [date, open, high, low, close values]
const series = chart
            .addOHLCSeries({ positiveFigure: OHLCFigures.Candlestick })
            .add(ohlcDataArr);
chart.getDefaultAxisX().fit();
chart.getDefaultAxisY().fit();
```

Only about 40 or 50 candles are shown but should be 43,000?

Is there a way to turn off candlestick chart aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the aggregation call [`ohlcSeries.setFigureAutoFitting(false)`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.2.0/classes/ohlcseries.html#setfigureautofitting).

```js
const { lightningChart, emptyFill, OHLCFigures } = lcjs;

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({ container: document.getElementById('chart-root') })
const ohlcDataArr = []; // contains 30 days 1-min data [date, open, high, low, close values]
const series = chart
            .addOHLCSeries({ positiveFigure: OHLCFigures.Candlestick })
            .setFigureAutoFitting(false)
            .add(ohlcDataArr);
chart.getDefaultAxisX().fit();
chart.getDefaultAxisY().fit();
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't vote up your answer as Im too new but I will try it